# How do you specify which navigation list to create a style rule for?

Tags: css, list, nav

Im creating a CSS file a HTML file I was given. It tells me to create a style rule for the horizontal list. I'm not sure how to specify which list i'm editing when creating the CSS file. Here is what I'm working with:

```
     <nav class="horizontal">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>

     <nav class="vertical">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Pizza</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Salad</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Pasta</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sandwiches</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Pocket Pizzas</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Fish &amp; Shrimp</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Chicken &amp; Wings</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Beverages</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Dessert</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Download Menu</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Catering Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
```

Comment: `nav.horizontal` or simply `.horizontal`.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're new to CSS.

CSS rules take two parts: the selector, targeting the element(s) to style, and the style properties to effect.

So the question in your case becomes: what selector will target the horizontal nav? Looking at your HTML, the element in question has a class, `.horizontal`, so:

```
.horizontal { /* style rules here */ }
```

In case there's a risk of other, non-`nav` elements having the same class, you can tighten your selector to match `nav` elements only:

```
nav.horizontal { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I am new...however, I had it correct, but misspelled horizontal as I was typing and didn't catch it right away. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

For this we use selectors in css 
CSS selectors allow you to select and manipulate HTML element(s)

as you have provided class for your list you will use
you have to use

```
.horizontal{

//rules goes here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a example how it looks:

```
nav ul { list-style: none; }
.horizontal { display: inline; }
```